# Mindlessly clicked days old phishing email link appeared dead

Tags: malware, email, phishing, scan

Was multitasking and mindlessly clicked Squarespace phishing email. Page didn't load, and right away I realized my mistake. Completed several malware scans which came back clean. The button link source was `https://sqwe7.com/`.

The domain was registered on Aug 8, I got the email Aug 9, but didn't click till Aug 11. The domain is no longer active.

Did my getting to the email late save me? I searched but can't find any other history on the domain other than it being tagged as phishing Aug 9. Couldn't find any other links when inspecting the source of the link, unless I am missing something, which is very possible.

Answer (score -1):

You're fine,

Just clicking the link will have been harmless if the page didn't load. As long as you don't download/install something or enter personal details on sites like that you've little to worry about.

Comment: Just because there may have been nothing shown on the screen does not mean that the page didn't load something in the background.

Comment: The domain was no longer active on DNS level, nothing could have been loaded

Comment: -1: Claiming that somebody is safe without conclusive evidence indicating it is a **very dangerous** thing to suggest.